# How can I activate debug logs with "to be continuous"?

Tags: gitlab-ci, to-be-continuous

I'm using [to be continuous](https://gitlab.com/groups/to-be-continuous) templates in my GitLab projects, but sometimes job fail and I lack debug information to troubleshoot the problem.

How can I activate debug logs in [to be continuous](https://gitlab.com/groups/to-be-continuous) pipeline jobs ?

For instance by enabling verbosity in every used tool (Maven, curl, kubectl, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of *to be continuous* templates enable debug logs when `$TRACE` is set.

So you may simply manually run your pipeline, and set `TRACE=1` interactively (any non-empty value is okay).

/!\ this is different (and complementary) to GitLab's [CI_DEBUG_TRACE](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#enable-debug-logging) variable.